# Serve multiple ghost

Tags: apache, server, ghost-blog, ghost

I am tring to serve multiple ghost in the same server under different domains, but both of them open the first instant 
which was installed in:
/var/www/ghost
and its config.js file contain:

```
production: {
        url: 'http://myfirstdomain.com/blog',
......
filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
.....
server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
.....
```

and its httpd conf file contain:

```
<Location /blog>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://localhost:2368/blog
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:2368/blog
</Location>
```

The Second instant was installed in:
/var/www/ghosth
and its config.js file:

```
production: {
        url: 'http://myseconddomain.com/blog',
......
filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghosth.db')
.....
server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2777'
.....
```

and its httpd conf file contain:

```
<Location /blog>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://localhost:2777/blog
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:2777/blog
</Location>
```

I run the tow instant in a different ports and domains but when I visit them

```
http://myfirstdomain.com/blog
http://myseconddomain.com/blog
```

I found the same instant (NOT only the same database)

so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the configuration of your server. So have you check if the mod-proxy is enabled?

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

I use Nginx instead of Apache so I can't really advice your for the configuration. If you didn't find it, this tutorial uses a different configuration: [Ghostforbeginners multi Ghost Apache](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-proxy-ghost-through-apache-for-security-and-multi-blog-setup/)

The configuration file of the tutorial:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName your-url.com
     ServerAlias www.your-url.com
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
     ProxyPassReverse / http:/127.0.0.1:2368/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName your-second-url.com
     ServerAlias www.your-second-url.com
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for you.. I followed the tutorial but it didn't work for me.. the `<VirtualHost *:80>` didn't work at all with ghost!. only `<Location>` directive worked, but it causes the problem which I explained. if you need any configuration file from my server tell me please.

Comment: I only know this type of configuration for Apache. If your server only serves Ghost, you can try the configuration with Nginx. The configuration files are located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sitename`

I write a tutorial with all the steps to install this server if you need more details: [Install multiple Ghost CMS](https://medium.com/pixel-for-creative-people/install-multi-ghost-cms-on-digitalocean-85f7c73ed782)